# How to match on concrete types of generic struct fields?

Tags: generics, rust

I'm playing around with the lambda calculus, but since I'm not too generics-savvy, I would like to confirm my understanding of some things and resolve an error. Consider the following definitions:

```
pub trait Term {} // a lambda term - a variable, an abstraction or an application

pub struct Var(pub usize); // a variable, De Bruijn style
pub struct Abs<T: Term>(T); // an abstraction
pub struct App<T: Term, U: Term>(T, U); // application of T on U
```

I understand (i.e. otherwise it doesn't work) that I need `App` to be generic over `<T: Term, U: Term>` as opposed to just `<T: Term>` to be able to e.g. apply a `Var` to an `App`, i.e. to have an `App(Var(x), App(...))`.

The aforementioned structs are all `Term`s:

```
impl Term for Var {}
impl<T: Term> Term for Abs<T> {}
impl<T: Term> Term for App<T, T> {}
```

Interesting that I don't need `App<T, U>` here, but hopefully so far so good - now I would like to implement `fmt::Display` for the aforementioned structs:

```
use std::fmt;
use std::fmt::Display;

impl fmt::Display for Var {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.0)
    }
}

impl<T: Term+Display> Display for Abs<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "λ{}", self.0)
    }
}
```

These two `impl`s work just fine; I'm including them since the next one relies on them:

```
impl<T: Term+Display> Display for App<T, T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match *self {
            App(Var(_), Var(_)) => write!(f, "{}{}", self.0, self.1),
            _ => unimplemented!()
        }
    }
}
```

But it fails with:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\ast.rs:34:8
   |
34 |                    App(Var(_), Var(_)) => write!(f, "{}{}", self.0, self.1),
   |                        ^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found struct `ast::Var`
   |
   = note: expected type `T`
   = note:    found type `ast::Var`
```

I would like to print `App` differently based on the types of its contents. I tried to find a related question, but they mostly revolve around associated types. Is there a simple solution or do I have to rework the definitions?

Comment: *Interesting that I don't need `App<T, U>` here* — that's because you are saying that `Term` is only implemented when both children of `App` are the **same type**. `App<u8, u8>` is OK, `App<u8, u32>` would not be.

Comment: This means I do need it after all - I might not have triggered an error yet, but I want different variations of `App` to be `Term`s too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to print `App` differently based on the types of its contents.

That's easy enough, just implement `Display` for every unique type of `App` you wish to be able to print:

```
use std::fmt;

struct App<T, U>(T, U);

impl fmt::Display for App<i32, bool> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Awesome choice!")
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for App<bool, String> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Woah, a string? Really?")
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", App(42i32, false));
    println!("{}", App(true, "wow".to_string()));
}
```

You can also accept further types that have their own generics:

```
impl<T> fmt::Display for App<Vec<T>, char> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{} of them; {}", self.0.len(), self.1)
    }
}
```

Note that this has no `unimplemented!` call; everything is checked at compile time:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `App<bool, bool>: std::fmt::Display` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:24:24
   |
24 |         println!("{}", App(true, false));
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `App<bool, bool>`
   |
   = note: `App<bool, bool>` cannot be formatted with the default formatter; try using `:?` instead if you are using a format string
   = note: required by `std::fmt::Display::fmt`
```

This has a close analog in the standard library: [`Cursor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html). This type accepts a generic, but all of the interesting functionality is only implemented for a handful of concrete types like `&[u8]` or `Vec<u8>`.

> but it still causes trouble, e.g. with `App<Var, App>`, because the inner `App` expects 2 type arguments again

Yes, you have to specify the generics because `App` *isn't a type*, it's only a stepping stone towards one.

It all depends on what you want to do. The simplest is to just have an `App` composed of two types of any kind, so long as you don't use them:

```
impl<T, U> fmt::Display for App<i32, App<T, U>> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Semi-awesome")
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to display the `App`, then you need to restrict the generics such that `App` is displayable:

```
impl<T, U> fmt::Display for App<i32, App<T, U>>
    where App<T, U>: fmt::Display,
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "({}) squared!", self.1)
    }
}
```

Check it out with

```
fn main() {
    let a = App(42i32, false);
    println!("{}", a);
    let b = App(100, a);
    println!("{}", b);
    let c = App(100, b);
    println!("{}", c);
}
```

---

I have a guess that the follow up question will be something about having some kind of fallback or default case for all the non-special conditions. Something like:

```
impl fmt::Display for App<i32, bool> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Awesome choice!")
    }
}

impl<T: fmt::Display, U: fmt::Display> fmt::Display for App<T, U> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Boring: {} + {}", self.0, self.1)
    }
}
```

Nope, that won't compile! `i32` and `bool` **also implement `Display`** so it is ambiguous which implementation to select. At this point, you are into the realm of [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md). This forces you to truly understand the *orphan rules*.

As far as I understand the current implementation of specialization, you cannot specialize on a concrete type, only on traits.

Comment: I was wondering about several individual implementations, but it still causes trouble, e.g. with `App<Var, App>`, because the inner `App` expects 2 type arguments again - is there any way around it?